# Dynamical Systems - Find bifurcation point, draw bifurcation diagram and classify bifurcations

Tags: partial-derivative, dynamical-systems, bifurcation

So I am given a one dimensional system and I'm told that

$\dot x = f(x,\mu)$ with 
$f(x,\mu) = (x^2 - \mu)(\mu + 3x^2 -4x)$

I am asked to find the bifurcation points, then to draw a bifurcation diagram and also classify the bifurcation points.

Firstly, I know to be a bifurcation point, the point $(x, \mu)$ must satisfy $f(x,\mu)=0$ and also $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,\mu)=0$

So I calculated $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x, \mu)$ which gave $4(x-1)(3x^2-\mu)$

From this I managed to calculate 3 bifurcation points, $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$ and $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})$

Now this is where I got stuck, because surely I can't draw the bifurcation diagram without knowing the classification of each bifurcation point.

So I tried to get the classification for each point. I know to be a saddle-node bifurcation:

$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,\mu) \neq 0$
and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}f(x,\mu) \neq 0$

which allowed me to find that $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{3})$ was a saddle node bifurcation.

And to be a pitchfork bifurcation:

$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,\mu)=0$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}f(x,\mu)=0$, $\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial x^3}f(x,\mu) \neq 0$ and also $\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial \mu}f(x,\mu) \neq 0$

which meant that $(0,0)$ is a pitchfork bifurcation.

Now finally there are transcritical bifurcation which require:
$\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x^2}f(x,\mu) \neq 0 
 \\\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x \partial \mu}f(x,\mu) \neq 0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu}f(x,\mu) = 0$

but $(1,1)$ does not fit into any of these categories?

So my question is, how do I draw my bifurcation diagram and how do I classify these bifurcation points?

Edit: I have found a 4th bifurcation point, at $(\frac{-2}{3},\frac{4}{3})$

Comment: Yeah that $x=1$ and $x=\sqrt(\frac{u}{3})$. I did that and found those 3 bifurcation points!

Comment: You can describe what's happening when you change parameter even without relying on exact type of bifurcation. Just sketch the graph of $f(x)$ at bifurcation values of parameter and in between. At $\mu = 1$ this family of ODEs goes through non-codimension-1 bifurcation, but that's okay, you just have to draw $f(x)$ around $\mu =1$ to explain what's happening.

Comment: @Moo Yeah sorry, I didn't know how to do plus and minus in this format. But it is what I meant